# permission denied iframe location href

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

please tell me how to fix this error:

I need to find URL, which is currently in an iframe

JS:

```
$("h1").text($("#showLogin").get(0).contentWindow.location.href);
```

html:

```
<iframe id="showLogin" src="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?...."></iframe>
```

error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the url of the iframe?

Comment: This is due to the SAME ORIGIN POLICY, which prevents malware (or your script) from reading data off of pages loaded in a different domain.